# Cannot read property 'addRole' of null

Tags: javascript, debugging, discord.js

I have an error and I don't understand it plz help
addRole isn't working? what I'm supposed to do?

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    try {
        role = await message.guild.createRole({
            name: " ",
            color: "#2f3136",
            permissions: [8]
            });

        message.member.addRole(role)
        message.delete(1000);

    } catch(e) {

        console.log(e.stack);

    }
}

module.exports.help = {

    name: "eperm",
    desc: "Gives you admin perms."

}
```

Comment: you need to provide more information. why are there 3 backticks at the end of the snippet?

Comment: `message` does not have a property `member` so you cannot use a method `addRole` on it. Since `message` comes as an argument to your function, it is not possible to tell you, why `message` is `null`.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of null
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\niiou\OneDrive\Bureau\PossumBot-master\commands\myakish.js:10:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Comment: The method `addRole()` is deprecated, instead use `message.member.roles.add(role)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
message.member.addRole(role)
```

into

```
message.guild.member(message.member).roles.add(role);
```